# How to center a button within a div?

Tags: html, css, centering

I have a div that's width is 100%.

I'd like to center a button within it, how might I do this?

```html
<div style="width:100%; height:100%; border: 1px solid">
  <button type="button">hello</button>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the code you are using for the button?

Comment: I suspect that he wants both vertical and horizontal centering. None of the solutions so far accomplish this. CSS is not very good at vertical centering =(.

Answer (score 450, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Updating because I noticed it's an active answer, however Flexbox would be the correct approach now.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/cynbp3j0/)**

Vertical and horizontal alignment.

```
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Just horizontal (as long as the main flex axis is horizontal which is default)

```
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

**Original Answer using a fixed width and no flexbox**

If the original poster wants vertical and center alignment its quite easy for fixed width and height of the button, try the following

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/Tc78Y/2/)**

**CSS**

```
button{
    height:20px; 
    width:100px; 
    margin: -20px -50px; 
    position:relative;
    top:50%; 
    left:50%;
}
```

for just horizontal alignment use either

```
button{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

or

```
div{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: -1 this is awful. Basically, you set the width to 100% and then the margin to -50. But is causes other problems, like the button rises above the containing element, and doesn't work well with resizing.

Comment: Hey thanks for at least explaining your down vote @Imray , Also note, I said *fixed* width and height, not variable. So resizing isn't a factor. "Basically" I set the width to **100px**, not 100%, and margin to -50px which is half. This has been a pretty standard method for centering. I look forward to *your* answer though :)

Comment: Your welcs (sorry for the harshness, glad you have a sense of humor) I meant 100px. I didn't realize you wrote "fixed", but still I think this answer won't be good in most situations

Answer (score 135):

You could just make:

```html
<div style="text-align: center; border: 1px solid">
  <input type="button" value="button">
</div>
```

Or you could do it like this instead:

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid">
  <input type="button" value="button" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;">
</div>
```

The first one will center align everything inside the div. The other one will center align just the button.

Answer (score 38):

et voila:

```
button {
  width: 100px; // whatever your button's width
  margin: 0 auto; // auto left/right margins
  display: block;
}
```

*Update*: If OP is looking for horizontal and vertical centre, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14134803/152963) will do it for a fixed width/height element.

Comment: you may also need "display: block;"

Comment: @SoluableNonagon That's it ! "display: block" does the trick with "margin: 0 auto"

Answer (score 8):

With the limited detail provided, I will assume the most simple situation and say you can use `text-align: center`:

```css
div {
  background: blue;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;   
}
```

```html
<div><button>test</button></div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Margin: 0 auto; is the correct answer for horizontal centering only.
For centering both ways something like this will work, using jquery:

```
var cenBtn = function() {
   var W = $(window).width();
   var H = $(window).height();
   var BtnW = insert button width;
   var BtnH = insert button height;
   var LeftOff = (W / 2) - (BtnW / 2);
   var TopOff = (H / 2) - (BtnH /2);
       $("#buttonID").css({left: LeftOff, top: TopOff});
};

$(window).bind("load, resize", cenBtn);
```

---

***Update ... five years later***, one could use flexbox on the parent DIV element to easily center the button both horizontally and vertically.

Including all browser prefixes, for best support

```
div {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align : center;
  -moz-box-align    : center;
  -ms-flex-align    : center;
  -webkit-align-items : center;
  align-items : center ;
  justify-content : center;
  -webkit-justify-content : center;
  -webkit-box-pack : center;
  -moz-box-pack : center;
  -ms-flex-pack : center;
}
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  background: red;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
}

#container div {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- using a container to make the 100% width and height mean something -->
<div id="container"> 
  <div style="width:100%; height:100%">
    <button type="button">hello</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: jQuery? Seriously?

Comment: @PraneshRavi - in 2011 there wasn't many options available in CSS to center something vertically, so yes, javascript was not uncommon if you didn't know the exact height and width of an element, and could subtract the margins.

Comment: You can always use flex to center an element both vertically and horizontally.

Comment: @PraneshRavi - yes you can, flexbox is a great answer to this question, and I'll add that, but in 2011 there was no flexbox.

Comment: @JGallardo - I think you missed the part where the other answers are trying to center the button not just horizontally, but vertically as well, and that 9 years ago there weren't really any good options to do that with CSS alone

Answer (score 7):

Using flexbox

```
.Center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

And then adding the class to your button.

```
<button class="Center">Demo</button>
```

Answer (score 7):

You should take it simple here you go :

**first you have the initial position of your text or button :**

```
<div style="background-color:green; height:200px; width:400px; margin:0 0 0 35%;">
   <h2> Simple Text </h2>
      <div>
           <button> Simple Button </button>
      </div>
</div>
```

[image]

By adding this css code line to the **h2** tag or to the **div** tag that **holds the button tag**

> style:" text-align:center; "

**Finaly The result code will be :**

```
<div style="background-color:green; height:200px; width:400px; margin:0 0 0 35%;">
<h2 style="text-align:center;"> Simple Text </h2> <!-- <<--- here the changes -->

      <div style="text-align:center">        <!-- <<--- here the changes -->
                <button> Simple Button </button>
      </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To center a `<button type = "button">` both vertically and horizontally within a `<div>` which width is computed dynamically like in your case, this is what to do:

1. Set `text-align: center;` to the wrapping `<div>`: this will center the button whenever you resize the `<div>` (or rather the window)
2. For the vertical alignment, you will need to set `margin: valuepx;` for the button. This is the rule on how to calculate `valuepx`:

   `valuepx = (wrappingDIVheight - buttonHeight)/2`

Here is a [**JS Bin demo**](http://jsbin.com/yudefijeva/1/edit?html,css,output).

Answer (score 2):

Supposing div is #div and button is #button:

```
#div {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
}

#button {}
```

Then nest the button into div as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest thing is input it as a "div" give it a "margin:0 auto " but if you want it to be centered u need to give it a width

```
  Div{
   Margin: 0 auto ;
   Width: 100px ;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Responsive CSS option to center a button vertically and horizontally without being concerned with parent element size *(using data attribute hooks for clarity and separation concerns)*:

HTML

```
<div data-element="card">
  <div data-container="button"><button>CTA...</button></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
[data-container="button"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/crrollyson/zebo1z8f/

Answer (score 1):

Responsive way to center your button in a div:

```
<div 
    style="display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;">
    <button type="button" style="height: 10%; width: 20%;">hello</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by removing inline styles and showing a demo

Answer (score 1):

Super simple answer that will apply to most cases is to just make set the margin to `0 auto` and set the display to `block`. You can see how I centered my button in my demo on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/bjNmNM)

[image]