# Centering an item in the dead center of a page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place some large text in the dead center of the page. I only want (prefer) a body tag in the page and nothing else. I've tried using `display: table-cell` and setting the `vertical-alignment` to `middle` but that did not work with a `height: 100%`

I then found another question on stackoverflow which addressed this problem but I realized it does not work with bigger font. This is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/aECYS/

Comment: dead center? set it `margin: auto`.

Comment: look at the fiddle, they did that. problem is they did more. And "dead center" implies top/bottom not just left/right especially when you look at the code they wrote and see `top:50%` is in there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Push the div to top and left based on the width and height specified.

**CSS**

```
 body{ background-color: #000;}
    div{
        background-color: #000;
        width:800px; 
        height: 200px; line-height: 200px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%; margin-top:-100px;
        left: 50%; margin-left:-400px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 100px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #ccc; text-align:center
    }​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aECYS/4/)**

Comment: Note: This will only work with 1 line of text because of `line-height`. Good solution still though +1

Answer (score 1):

If your position is absolute then you move your text anywhere you want change your css attribute with this.

Note: Absolutely positioned elements can overlap other elements.

```
position: absolute;
top: 37%;
left: 34%;
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/aECYS/2/)

Set width and height as 100%

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
```

Then the text center with the different screen size

Comment: how about different screen sizes and devices ?

Comment: why -1 i say the answer for that

Answer (score 1):

```
.Absolute-Center {
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
 }
```

is the best way, choose your class though here.