# Bootstrap 3: How can I horizontally center the navbar collapsed button?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am talking about the small button on the right:

http://imageshack.us/scaled/thumb/32/7n9i.png

I have tried the following CSS selector, without success:

```
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: try it inside a container div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.navbar-toggle 
{
    float:none;

}   
.navbar-header
{
    text-align:center;
}
```

See also: [How to center a button within a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560832/how-to-center-a-button-within-a-div)

**update**

maybe set padding-right of the button too:

```
margin-right: 26px
```

(15px + half the size of the button)