# How do I center a button within it's div class

Tags: html, css

I have a button that needs to be centered in it's div class ex. div="sanfrancisco-image". It's placed 17px from the bottom of the box, however it will appear center, even though I've placed justify-self:center; and align-items: center; tabs.

Here's the codepen link: https://codepen.io/holmedw/pen/KrvJEb

```
  .btn {
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 2px black solid;
  border-radius: 1px;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  bottom: 17px;
  justify-self: center;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center a button within a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560832/how-to-center-a-button-within-a-div)

Answer (score 0):

No need for the align-items and justify-self. not sure they do any good, so try to remove them. on the css of the button? => set the following:

```
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
```

try that and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to get what you want is to add `position: relative` to the `.our-story-block, .our-dna-block, .sanfrancisco-block` then you add a new `div` to include your `button`, like `<div class="btn"><button>See More</button></div>`. Set that `div` to `position: absolute; bottom: 17px; width: 100%; left: 0;` so it would center the absolute div inside a relative element. You won't need to include those values in your `.btn` css class anymore so just remove them.

```
  .btn {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 17px;
   } 
   .btn > button{
        padding: 0 20px;
        height: 40px;
        font-size: 1em;
        font-weight: 700;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        border: 2px black solid;
        border-radius: 1px;
        background: transparent;
        cursor: pointer;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. This is the one that worked. For further clarification why did you do the <div class="btn"><button> instead of <button class="btn>? What's the logic/thinking behind this? I need to know for my own sake. Because without your comment I would't  have been able to do this. Thanks,

Comment: @EdwardHolmes I'm no expert but `<button>` is an `inline element`, you were setting the styling elements to the button itself. When you add position absolute, `<button>` behaves as a `block level element` & that were why you was able to set `bottom: 17px` value to it. To be able to center the button in your case, I added a block level element with absolute position to the parent block `.sanfrancisco-block`. Center any items in that element and position it in the bottom as you wanted. Learn more about inline elements 
 >> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements