# Is there any way to put button into center of div?

Tags: html, css

[Image is attached what i wanna get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSJVD.png)

Hello everyone I tried to get help form google and it did not work for me i have tried display as table-cells, table, flex, grid etc. So i am looking for some help if you can thank you everyone.

```
<html>
    <style>
.contact-us{
    background-color:  grey;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 230px;
    padding: 50px 300px 50px 300px;
    display: grid;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.contact-us .btn{
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  display: grid;
}
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="contact-us">
            <h2>CONTACT US TODAY</h2>
              <h5>Have any questions or comments? Need a WINZ quote? Call us at (022) 1736590.</h5>
              <button class="btn">CONTACT US</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please put your code of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add some code so we can see what you have. We need a minimum of code to replicate the problem and fix it. Also the image isn't showing much.

Comment: Hi mate sorry about delay using it first time. I have added some code may be help us.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to center a button within a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560832/how-to-center-a-button-within-a-div)

Comment: You can use css positioning here

Answer (score 1):

I like the flex-box approach.

We'll make the **body** element full height and then center your **contact-us** element in the center of the body using **flex-box**.

```html
<html>
  <style>=
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      background-color:  grey;
      min-height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .contact-us{
      text-align: center;
      color: #fff;
    }

    .contact-us .btn{
      width: 100px;
      height: 30px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 13px;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="contact-us">
      <h2>CONTACT US TODAY</h2>
      <h5>Have any questions or comments? Need a WINZ quote? Call us at (022) 1736590.</h5>
      <button class="btn">CONTACT US</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi mate this one did not work not too sure why

Comment: Hey mate, i've updated my answer with a new approach

Answer (score 1):

```css
.contact-us {
text-align: center;
}

h2{
text-align:left;
}

h5{
text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <style>
.contact-us{
    background-color:  grey;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 230px;
    color: #fff;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.contact-us .btn{
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="contact-us">
            <h2>CONTACT US TODAY</h2>
              <h5>Have any questions or comments? Need a WINZ quote? Call us at (022) 1736590.</h5>
              <button class="btn">CONTACT US</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Make it much shorter.
no need to use flex.!
flex is partial supported in IE and its not good to use.

```css
div {
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Im Centered!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi mate it did go through but now button is going to next div and there is huge gap between all three lines

Comment: I changed the snippet thats what you're lookng for?