# How do I get my buttons centered without 100% width?

Tags: html, css, width, display

I've looked at a few solutions but I'm pretty sure I just can't code correctly. Whenever I use "display:block" the buttons display vertically but the clickable area has a 100% width, when I use "display:inline-block", the buttons don't display vertically but remove the 100% width issue.

HTML:

```
<body style="margin: 0;">
    <div class="banner">
    <a href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/Homepage.html">
        <!-- <button type="button" class="logo"><img src="Logo.png"/></button> -->
    </a>
    <div class="center-buttongroup">
        <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/Simulator.html">
        <button class="buttonone">one</button>
        </a>
        <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/Websites.html">
        <button class="buttonone">two</button>
        </a>
    </div>
    
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

````
.center-buttongroup{
    padding-top: 15%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    display:table;

}
.buttonone{
    display:table;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    padding: 20px 80px;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #277fe3;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.0.2);
    color:white;
}

.buttonone:hover {background-color: #1c5693}```

I've tried using

display:table;
float:left;
clear:left;


but I can't seem to center the buttons and now I'm lost.

output (https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeHVM.png)

I am a beginner please bare with me
````

Comment: It is explained very well in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7560887